# how to remove empty line when reading text file using C#

Tags: c#

i have text file and read it using stream reader, when my file is having empty line along with data, it does not read any thing. how to remove the empty line using C#.

Comment: Can you show an example please? And some code?

Comment: How are you reading the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should use the method "ReadLine()" from the StreamReader in a loop. When you receive an empty line, simply check if the string obtained from ReadLine() is empty. If it is, ignore the line.
Try something like:

```
    StreamReader input = new StreamReader("...");
    String line = null;

    do 
    {
    line = input.ReadLine();

    if (line == null)
    {
    return;
    }

    if (line == String.Empty)
    {
    continue;
    }

    // Here you process the non-empty line

    } while (true);
```

Comment: Could shorten the ifs to `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))` etc...

Comment: The "null" check is needed to allow exiting from the loop. The empty string check, on the other hand, simply indicated an empty line and was not a reason to exit from the loop. Hence, the two conditions can't be joined together through "if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))"

Answer (score 17):

You haven't shown any code, and your description is pretty woolly, but as of .NET 4 this would be a very easy way to do what you want:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines().Where(line => line != "");
```

Note that it won't perform any trimming, so a line with only spaces in would still be returned.

Also note that the code above *doesn't* read the file when you just execute that line - it will only read it when you try to iterate over `lines`, and will read it again *every* time you iterate over `lines`. If you want to read it into memory all in one go, you might want:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines().Where(line => line != "").ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code:

```
private void ReadFile()
{
    try
    {
        string line = null;
        System.IO.TextReader readFile = new StreamReader("C:\\csharp.net-informations.txt");
        while (true)
        {
            line = readFile.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(line);
            }
        }
        readFile.Close();
        readFile = null;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: this code will loop forever, won't close the File when readline throws and it doesn't filter empty lines. Btw nulling the readFile variable is redundant in the times of Garbage Collection