# c# reading from a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am reading a text file which has some format. I am skipping the first two lines and then reading firstname, second name and then creating a list of firstname , secondname. Everything is working file but when the last line is empty then my program stops working and gives an error. How to avoid whiltespace so that my program dont stop my code is:

```
public void Read(string filename, List<Person> person)
{
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
   {
       sr.ReadLine();
       sr.ReadLine();
       while (!sr.EndOfStream)
       {
           FirstName= sr.EndOfStream ? string.Empty : sr.ReadLine();
           LastName= sr.EndOfStream ? string.Empty : sr.ReadLine();
           person.Add(new Person(FirstName, LastName));
       }
   }
}
```

File format is

```
Students Data
Description
FirstName
LastName
FirstName
LastName
FirstName
LastName
FirstName
LastName
```

Comment: Care to explain what the error is?

Comment: Does he call `sr.ReadLine()` twice?

Comment: If you can, consider modifying your file format. Seperate delimiters should be used between fields (first name, last name) and records (the pair of names - a person). CSV is perfect for this application. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 2):

What is going wrong, is that `sr.ReadLine()` will be executed regardless of whether the document has a next line or not, so it might return null (if you've run out of lines)
Simply check whether `sr.ReadLine()` returns `null`

```
public void Read(string filename, List<Person> person)
{
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
   {
       sr.ReadLine();
       sr.ReadLine();
       while (!sr.EndOfStream)
       {
           String FirstName = sr.ReadLine() ?? "-not defined-";
           String LastName = sr.ReadLine() ?? "-not defined-";

           person.Add(new Person(FirstName, LastName));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Aren't those inline ifs enough to prevent ReadLine when the end of the stream is reached?

Comment: yeah, just simplified the answer.

Comment: Op ran into trouble because of the way he did his checks using `sr.EndOfStream`, he would only check if there were more *bytes* defined in the stream, not if there were still more *lines* ahead in the stream.

Comment: And if i'm going to be nitpicky, OP, please return a `List<Person>` from your function instead of passing a pre-existing one as parameter.
C# Lists can be merged quite easily you know.

Comment: IMO it is better to set undefined names to null and let the display code handle placeholders. Potentially your display may not want to include partial name pairs (last name undefined) but you may still want it in the list. If you set it to a "-not defined-", the consuming code has no idea if the name is defined or not. As an extension, if the firstname is not defined, a person should certainly not be added.

Comment: @Gusdor agreed, definitely. Also, to add some clarity to what is happening, OP should log an event when this occurs, or at the least throw an exception so he can handle that further up in his program, but that is beyond the scope of the question a little ;)

Comment: And like you stated earlier, doing data formatting like this is just asking for trouble

Comment: @TimothyGroote is it an exceptional scenario? Be wary of chucking exceptions around. A person may not be required to have 2 names. Arguably, that should mean an empty line. All you really need to do is flag incomplete entries in some way. The file format is junk tbh :D

Comment: Oh snap! :P i wonder how he handles people with more than two names.

Comment: i am getting an error if my last line is blank or equals to ""

Answer (score 1):

You could create an adapter for the StreamReader class, something like this

```
public class NoBlankStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    public NoBlankStreamReader(FileStream fs) : base(fs) { }


    private bool IsBlank(string inString)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inString)) inString = inString.Trim();
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(inString);
    }


    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        string result= base.ReadLine();
        while (result!=null && IsBlank(result))
            result = base.ReadLine();
        return result;
    }
}
```

then use like this:

```
using (FileStream fs=File.OpenRead(@"test.txt"))
using (TextReader reader = new NoBlankStreamReader(fs))
{
    while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

or u can see the post:

[how to remove empty line when reading text file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314555/how-to-remove-empty-line-when-reading-text-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Not a bad way either!